# CSS style my django table

Tags: python, css, django

[image: picture of my table]

I rendered my table with django table2 and above link how it looks like.

I style it with CSS like this:

```
thead {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    font-color: white;
}
```

It looks like the background-color works and it shows green
However the font-color did not turn white. Strangely it is purple/blue. Any idea why?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they hyperlinks? They look like it. Those are the colors for visited and "non-visited" hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are hyperlinks (`a` tag) for which the browser has **default** colors.
You can set the color of hyperlinks like that:

**For unvisited links**

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}
```

**Visited links**

```
a:visited {
    color: green;
}
```

**Hover over links**

```
a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}
```

**Selected links**

```
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Or if you want for all the same color:

```
a {
 color:white;
}
```

If you also want to get rid of the underlines you can set the `text-decoration` property to `none`:

```
text-decoration:none;
```

Comment: Also, i find out that in order to disable the hyperlink, you need to go to your django table 2 class and put down:  orderable = False

Comment: Hi @LanceQi. I see you are new here, but if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark on the left. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.